# How to identify the properties of a class of data type bool or char in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

```
unsigned int outCount, i;

objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);

for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++)
{
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];

    NSString *propertyType = [NSString stringWithCString: property_getAttributes(property) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

propertyType always Tc,V_xxx whether this property is bool or char.

How to identify the properties of a class of data type bool or char in objective-c ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot because in Objective-C BOOL is unsigned char.
So you can do something like that

```
BOOL b = 10;
NSLog(@"%d", b); // 10
```

bool can be just 0 and 1:

```
bool b = 10;
NSLog(@"%d", b); // 1
```

So there is no way to make 100% distinction between BOOL and char.

Comment: Some platforms use 'B' for BOOL (currently only arm64 iOS). Otherwise this is correct.